# regex for decimal value restrict 16 digit

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I want a regex expression to restrict input decimal value at max. 16 digits or 15 digits and one character (including decimal point)

I found below Regex it is working find in C# code but when i am using it in  TextEdit xaml as mask. (DevExpress) throwing exception `syntax error`:

[image: Exception]

Mask:

```
^(?:(?=.{0,16}$)\d*\.\d+|\d{0,16})[kKmMbBtT]?$
```

TextEdit Xaml:

```
<dxe:TextEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaskType="RegEx"
     Mask="(?:(?=.{0,16}$)[0-9]*([.]?[0-9]+)|[0-9]{0,16})[kKmMbBtT]?"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"
     EditValue="{Binding DecValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Margin="10,33,0,0"/>
```

Purpose I want to achieve from it:

- User can enter at 16 digits decimal value (including decimal point) or
- user can enter 15 digit and one character (including decimal point)
- He can enter only decimal point one time
- Total length of input string must not more than 16 characters.

Comment: MaskType="RegEx" Mask="(?:(?=.{0,16}$)[0-9]*([.]?[0-9]+)|[0-9]{0,16})[kKmMbBtT]?"

Comment: @GrantWinney The exception is: `syntax error`, thrown directly in `XAML` editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501):

> Extended Regular Expressions provide almost unlimited flexibility to
>   create input masks. The syntax used by masks in this mode is similar
>   to the syntax defined by the POSIX ERE specification. Back referencing
>   is not supported.

So, you cannot use grouping constructs such `(?: subexpression)` or `(?= subexpression)` etc. You can use some weird mask like this:

```
\d{0,16}|\d{14}\R.\d{1}|\d{13}\R.\d{1,2}|\d{12}\R.\d{1,3}|\d{11}\R.\d{1,4}|\d{10}\R.\d{1,5}|\d{9}\R.\d{1,6}|\d{8}\R.\d{1,7}|\d{7}\R.\d{1,8}|\d{6}\R.\d{1,9}|\d{5}\R.\d{1,10}|\d{4}\R.\d{1,11}|\d{3}\R.\d{1,12}|\d{2}\R.\d{1,13}|\d{1}\R.\d{1,14}|\R.\d{1,15}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<dxe:TextEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaskType="RegEx"
     Mask="\d{0,16}|\d{14}\R.\d{1}|\d{13}\R.\d{1,2}|\d{12}\R.\d{1,3}|\d{11}\R.\d{1,4}|\d{10}\R.\d{1,5}|\d{9}\R.\d{1,6}|\d{8}\R.\d{1,7}|\d{7}\R.\d{1,8}|\d{6}\R.\d{1,9}|\d{5}\R.\d{1,10}|\d{4}\R.\d{1,11}|\d{3}\R.\d{1,12}|\d{2}\R.\d{1,13}|\d{1}\R.\d{1,14}|\R.\d{1,15}"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"
     EditValue="{Binding DecValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Margin="10,33,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Hi nempoBu4, Thanks for your response. This Regex is fine according to situation but it is too lengthy. Akif